# ApplicationContext.getBeansOfType with arguments

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, arguments, javabeans

Is it possible to call getBeansOfType, or similar method, with arguments which would be passed to the constructor? Or am I stumbling upon some anti-pattern?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: To whose constructor?

Comment: No, not with `getBeansOfType` you can use [`getBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to pass constructor/reference arguments to a prototype bean or factory method.

Comment: @AndreiStefan To the beans constructor

Comment: `getBeansOfType` just returns instances, without actually passing anything to the actual beans' constructors.